# Manually trigger/open Piwik consent manager?

Tags: matomo, cookieconsent, piwiktracker

Piwik provides js snippets for a consent manager popup and an embedded version for a privacy page.

I want to give the website users the posbiliy to change their consent, e.g. to watch a YouTube video without navigating to the privacy page, right away. Therefore a placeholder is displayed instead of the video.

The easiest way would be to trigger the consent popup manually from that placeholder image by click.

Piwik do not have documented such a functionality.

Does someone know a clever workaround to display the popup again after initially setting consents. By default the popup will only occur again when deleting cookies and local storage in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reduced the html from privacy page to show only the button.

```
<div id="ppms_cm_privacy_settings" data-editor-centralize="true"
        data-main-container="true" data-root="true">
    <div data-disable-select='true'>
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="ppms_cm_privacy_settings_button">Privacy settings
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will raise the privacy policy dialog right at the placeholder.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! One can also get rid of the `data-*` attributes, what seems to be important is the container ID'd as `.._privacy_settings` and the `button` ID'd as `.._privacy_settings_button`.

Comment: Just noticed that the Piwik API (since v12) introduced this in its JS API via a call to `ppms.cm.api('openConsentForm')`. One can also supply fulfilled/rejected callback parameters. See docs: https://developers.piwik.pro/en/latest/consent_manager/js_api/index.html#open-consent-form